# Angularjs Create Table Ng-Repeat with json data

Tags: angularjs, json, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm very new to angular js. My task is to create an html table from the JSON data from a web service.

**JSON data will be like:**

```
[{"StartTime":"07:00","Name":"xxxxxxxx","Slots":["07:00","07:15"]},{"StartTime":"07:30","Name":"xxxxxxxx","Slots":["07:30"]}]
```

Slots length will tell us how many rows to be merge.

Table should be like:

```
*-------------------------------*
| Time  |  Name                 |
*-------*-----------------------*
| 07:00 | xxxxxxxxxxx           |
|-------|                       |
| 07:15 |                       |
|-------|-----------------------|
| 07:30 | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx        |
|-------|-----------------------|
```

Comment: This is not an valid object or json

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what problems you have encountered

Comment: A.B Json Edited . Please have a look at that.

Comment: @SindhuVinodhini yes i edited too, see answer :)

Comment: @SindhuVinodhini StackOverflow is meant for solving your doubts, please post what you have tried and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your json, which was not valid. you can see in js or json object valiadator

**Working Demo:**

```js
angular.module('testApp',[]).controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items=[
{"StartTime":"07:00","Name":"xxxxxxxx","Slots":["07:00","07:15"]},
{"StartTime":"07:30","Name":"xxxxxxxx","Slots":["07:30"]}];
  });
```

```css
div.col {
  background:pink; 
  border-bottom:1px dotted black;
  padding:2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <table border="2">
      <tr>
         <td>Time</td>
         <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
         <td >
             <div class="col" ng-repeat="i in item.Slots"> {{i}}</div>
         </td>
          <td >{{item.Name}}</td>
       </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

It was quite tricky to do it with just a table alone with rowspan. You have to use ng-repeat-start/end. I also used $first to skip the first row of the nested repeat.

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in array">
      <td>{{item.Slots[0]}}</td>
      <td rowspan="{{item.Slots.length}}">{{item.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="slot in item.Slots" ng-if="!$first" ng-repeat-end>
      <td>{{slot}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FsjCt2un618tVEBsGk7N?p=preview